# Can we ever quantify the level of randomness within a (data collecting) experiment?

Tags: probability, sampling, inference, experiment-design, randomness

**Can we ever quantify the level of randomness within a (data collecting) experiment?**

We all know that "randomness" is both directly and indirectly required on different levels for various principles in statistics to hold when applied in the real world. I thought of two examples to illustrate the importance of randomness in statistics:

**1) Applied Example :** Suppose I have two friends who are conducting an experiment to find out the average height of a student at the university - both friends can only sample 50 students out of a total of 5000 students. The first friend finds out that the height of students on the basketball team are already posted on the internet : There are 30 players on the basketball team and all players are students at the university - the first friend thinks that this will make his work easier since now he only has to measure 20 students.  The second friend walks around the university and tries to measure a variety of different students. Since basketball players tend to be taller than the average person, and since the first friend's data is made up of many basketball students - his estimate of the average student height is likely to be taller than the true average student height. **Had he attempted to "include more randomness" within his experiment - his estimates might have been more realistic.**

**2) Theoretical Example:** Theorems in statistics such as the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem show that the empirical probability distribution created from random draws of some variable, will converge to the true cumulative probability distribution function of this variable (as the number of draws goes to infinity):

[image]

**However, this theorem relies on the fact that the draws are indeed random (i.i.d.).** My knowledge of pure math and probability theory is weak, but using logic : it would seem that if these draws were not random (i.i.d.), then the empirical probability distribution function of some variable made by random draws **will not** converge to the true cumulative probability distribution function of this variable.

These two examples bring me to my question.

**My question:** Can we ever quantify the amount of randomness within a (data collecting) experiment?

After collecting data, can we ever determine that "there is not enough randomness" within the data for applications of statistics to hold? Or is this the limit of the capabilities of statistics (self referential problem)?  Does randomness have a unit of measure?

Can we ever make conclusions stating that :since there was only "some randomness" in the experiment, the confidence intervals on our estimates will be much larger compared to had there been "more randomness" in our experiment?

Does answering this question require subject expertise, domain knowledge and heuristics to ascertain if "enough randomness was present" in the experiment?

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glivenko%E2%80%93Cantelli_theorem

Comment: It seems to me that this is really just a question about how robust are certain methods to violations of the i.i.d. assumption, no? Or am I missing something.